# Connect to database(in windows server) from outside

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I key all my database in PHPmyadmin and try to connect the database from outside (android apps), no idea how to setup and write db_config.php (server not local host)

Comment: PHPMyAdmin is a database **client**, not a database. Do not confuse MySQL with PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: ok , thanks , i am new in coding and keep tryin up 
But now i got a windows server 2012 , and i try to develop an android app , how do i let the app connect to the database(mySql which in windows server) , i can't find the solution on the internet .

Answer (score -1):

Is your server accessible from the rest of the world ? If not, you'r not be abble to access your database from the net.
Second, if your server is accessible, access from Apps (android, ios) come from the app itself (i.e with Angular, you have to call your PHP API as : http.get('https://myserver.srv/Account)

Your PHP script just have to connect locally on your databases, do the job and return an object to the client...

Comment: i am new in coding and still learning on , thanks for the answer 
so now i got a windows server 2012 , and i try to develop an android app 
any suggestion or way to let app(from outside) connect to database?